# Выводится изначальная цена

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def dis(price, discount):
    prise = price * (discount * 0.01)
    if prise - int(price) == 0:
        return int(price)
    else:
        return price


print(dis(1500, 50))
```

Comment: У вас ошибка в логике, судя по всему, потому что в обоих вариантах вернется `price`. Ну а в данном случае, переменная `prise` будет равна 750, значит сработает `else` и вернется 1500

Comment: @ClarkDevlin и всё же, как тогда сделать?

Comment: Новая цена называется prise, поэтому если хочется новой цены, то надо и возвращать новую цену, а не старую. А чтобы не было таких глупых ошибок, нужно давать переменным имена, отражающие их содержимое. Например, new_price

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def disc(price: int, discount: int) -> int:
    
        if not discount: # проверяет наличие скидки если она равна 0, то возвращает просто цену
            return price
    
        return price * (discount * 0.01) # возврат цены со скидкой
```

Comment: Комментировать ОП пока не могу

Answer (score 1):

Во первых проблема была с названием переменных:
@Эникейщик Новая цена называется prise, поэтому если хочется новой цены, то надо и возвращать новую цену, а не старую. А чтобы не было таких глупых ошибок, нужно давать переменным имена, отражающие их содержимое. Например, new_price

Во вторых у меня получалась не новая цена, а сама скидка. Потом нужно было еще вычесть из начальной цены

Comment: это ответ на вопрос или ответ на комментарий (видимо, от @Эникейщик)?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin это ответ на мой вопрос. И я также указал, кто ответил на него